# Django, browser display filename instead of the picture

Tags: django, django-templates

I am missing some element to display picture  attatched with each post on a blog created with Django instead of picture file name.

Many solutions to this kind of a problem were:

```
<img src="{{Object.picture.url}}"/>
```

On template I have tried:

1

```
<img src="{{ posts.title_picture.url }}"/>
```

2

```
<img src="{{title_picture.url}}"/>
```

Which resulted respectively in displaying those on the browser:

1.

pictureforpost1.png

2.

img

model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    title_picture = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True)
```

view:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
```

Seems like Django is finding the file. It is just not displaying the picture.

****Solution thanks to the below answers:****

changed

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

to 

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and added the following

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
   ...
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) 
# when served with STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT instead it 
# is not working so check difference in MEDIA and STATIC.
```

In general I was lacking (and still do :) ) basic knowledge on uploads and displaying the static files.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah because you havent given any path to upload the file to media folder in you model. Thus only the file name was saved in the database and not the file. Check how to upload images and display them in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you will create the new record for table Post then you have to upload the Image File so if you set the media url then it will store at the specified location.
Try to set the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in settings.py file Eg.

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

You can seen the details in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage).

Comment: please view solution in the edit section. Have gone through few django tutorials and have not seen any MEDIA or STATIC stuff explained properly anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

settings.py :

```
'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                ...
            ],
```

templates:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{title_picture.url}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `models.ImageField()` instead of  `models.FileField()`.
And must install 'Pillow' package with pip.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the code, you tried to get the image from a collection of Post rather than just one post.

Try to just display one of the post, if the syntax below doesn't work you can use the for loop to iterate through your collection.

```
<img src="{{ posts.first.title_picture.url }}"/>
```